# Write string with keywords being bold to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am running the code below in Jupyter notebook. I tested the code cannot achieve this goal. How should I revise it so that all my keywords can be written bold in excel?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

BOLD = '\033[1m'
END = '\033[0m'

keyword_list = ['cat', 'dog']

df = pd.DataFrame([{'c1':'I have a dog', 'c2':100}, {'c1':'I have a cat','c2':110}, {'c1':'sdsd','c2':120}])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in keyword_list:
        row['c1'] = row['c1'].replace(i, BOLD + i + END)
#         print(row['c1'])

from os.path import abspath, join

with pd.ExcelWriter(join(abspath(''),'test.xlsx')) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```